# 24V DC to +5V and -5V

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, negative-voltage

I need to convert 24V DC to +5V and -5V to power two op-amps (opa2134) and one ATtiny85 with minimal heat generated from the circuit.

What voltage regulator would you recommend ?

//Digis

Comment: Search for a dual complementary output charge pump

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution is to buy a small DC/DC converter with bipolar outputs in an oversized 24-pin DIP package.  Note - these usually require additional capacitors on the input and outputs.

If you want to grow it from scratch, I would go with a linear regulator for the +5 V (because the total load current is so low) and a non-isolated buck-boost converter to turn the +24 V into -5 V.  There are dozens of parts to choose from for this, including ones with the power transistors on-board.  Linear Technology (now a part of Analog Devices) is a good company for this.

Answer (score 2):

For less than 10mA total current per supply, consider an [LM7805](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua78.pdf) + [ICL7660](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/icl7660s-a.pdf). At the higher end the 7805 will get warm but it won't require a heat sink in most situations. It will draw approximately 20mA +5mA Iq from the supply at 10mA + 10mA output current, so the power dissipation will be (24-5)V * 20mA + 24V * 5mA = 500mW.

For higher asymmetric currents, like 50mA on the +5 and 10-20mA on the -5, you can consider a switching buck regulator and the same 7660 to turn the +5 into -5. Suitable switching regulators are the well established LM2596 or MC34063.

If you really need the ultra-low distortion amplifier you mentioned, you may wish to think about how to mitigate noise from a switching regulator if this could be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

> What voltage regulator would you recommend for 24V to +/-5 regulated ….with minimal heat generated from the circuit.

I'd suggest that the cheapest but not quite the lowest power would be to use two of the LM2596 based switching regulators readily available online:

[image]

These cost about $0.60 each and are a great replacement for older linear regulators. You'd need one for the +5 and one for the -5.

You can use one of these to generate a -5V supply simply by using a series diode to the unit, and grounding the OUT+ pin. The regulated -5V is available on the OUT- pin

The only downside of these regulators is that they ALWAYS draw a peak pulse current of 3A, so your 24V supply needs a reasonably high output capacitor to supply this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about cost, but want low noise, LDO regulated charge pump 100µA Quiescent Current use [LTC3260](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/linear-technology-analog-devices/LTC3260EDE-TRPBF/LTC3260EDE-TRPBFTR-ND/3248405).

But if you don't give any other requirements, how can you search or design or decide? ( collorary to *the best question has better specs*)

Comment: Minimum quantity...2500.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/linear-technology-analog-devices/LTC3260EDE-TRPBF/LTC3260EDE-TRPBFDKR-ND/8433337